# LocalDateTime parse to epoch seconds

Tags: java, java-8, localdate

I'm trying to parse a string of the following form 2010-10-12-18-43-55 to seconds since epoch in the current timezone. Here is what I tried

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = 
          DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
```

I.

```
String datatetime = "2010-10-12-18-43-55";
Instant.parse(datetime).toEpochMilli; 
//Throws 
//java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: 
//Text '2010-10-12-18-43-55' could not be parsed at index 10
```

II.

```
String datatetime = "2010-10-12-18-43-55";
Instant.from(LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, dateTimeFormatter)).toEpochMilli
//Throws 
//java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain Instant from 
//TemporalAccessor: 2010-10-12T18:43:55 of type 
//java.time.LocalDateTime type java.time.LocalDateTime
```

III.

```
String datatetime = "2010-10-12-18-43-55";
Instant.from(dateTimeFormatter.parse(datetime, new ParsePosition(0))).toEpochMilli
//Throws 
//java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain Instant from 
//TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2010-10-12T18:43:55 
//of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Can someone help me to solve this task?

Comment: are you sure that is java: `String datatetime = 2010-10-12-18-43-55;` ? kind of missing quotes, is it?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thanks, fixed.

Comment: You can fix attempt `II` using `Instant inst = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, dateTimeFormatter).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From the `Instant` [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) the `String` has to be in the format `2007-12-03T10:15:30.00Z`.
2. The `String` can't be parsed to an `Instant` because the timezone is missing. Try this:
   `ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.systemDefault());`
3. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.